# Intuition behind $t(t+1)(t+2)\cdots(t+n-1)$

Tags: combinatorics

We have the following formula: Let $t$ be indeterminate and fix $n\geq 0$. Then

\begin{equation}
\sum_{k=0}^n c(n,k)t^k = t(t+1)(t+2)\cdots(t+n-1)
\end{equation}

where $c(n,k) = \#$ of permutations with $k$ cycles. Does anyone have an intuitive explanation for understanding this formula? Thanks in advance.

Note: Even though I know $c(n,k)$ is called a signless Stirling number of the first kind, I have minimal understanding of what it is and how it is useful. I just started learning combinatorics and have not encountered many applications of Stirling numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is equivalent to the recurrence stated in the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_first_kind#Recurrence_relation): $c(n+1,k)=nc(n,k)+c(n,k-1)$. The [Combinatorial proof of this recurrence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_first_kind#Combinatorial_proof) on Wikipedia seems fairly intuitive. So the fact that these two are equal just requires the case $n=1$.